# Ghostscript: How to convert EPS to PDF with the same page size

Tags: pdf, converters, ghostscript, eps

I want to convert a EPS figure to a PDF figure with the same width and height.

The following command:

```
gswin32 -dSAFER -dNOPLATFONTS -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dMaxSubsetPct=100 \
  -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOutputFile="test.pdf" \
  -f "test.eps"
```

only produces a PDF file with the page size of a letter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the test EPS file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45318932/test.eps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPS files cannot contain a media size request. In the absence of any media size request Ghostscript uses the default.

However.....

From the documentation:

http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.15/Use.htm#EPS_parameters

**`-dEPSCrop`** :
    Crop an EPS file to the bounding box. This is useful when converting an EPS file to a bitmap.

Comment: Great. Can not accept two answers. But I have up-voted both of you.

Comment: @Leo: you should accept KenS' answer -- his was first... :-)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Done. :) Thanks KenS and Kurt.

Answer (score 4):

To make KenS' answer more explicit, using the `test.eps` sample file you linked to... the following command will suffice to do what you want:

```
gswin32                 \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite      \
 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer \
 -dEPSCrop              \
 -o test.pdf            \
  test.eps
```

The `-o test.pdf` is (for not too ancient versions of Ghostscript!) shorthand for `-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=test.pdf`.

Your `test.eps` uses a font named `/SHZENL+Tahoma_00`. Ghostscript will automatically embed this font, and it will be a subset by default (the prefix `SHZENL` may change in the PDF, though).

Here is a screenshot from the page the command from your question created. That page is `612 x 792 pts` (letter size):

[image]

Here is the screenshot from the page the command given in my answer created. Its page size is `360 x 216 pts`:

[image: Result when adding <code>-dEPSCrop</code>]

Comment: Great. Can not accept two answers. But I have up-voted both of you.